# No cache in Node.js server

Tags: node.js, caching

I have read that to avoid caching in Node.js, it is necessary to use:

```js
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

But I don't know how to use it because I get errors when I put that line in my code.

My function (where I think I have to program the Cache-Control header) is:

```js
function getFile(localPath, mimeType, res) {
  fs.readFile(localPath, function(err, contents) {
    if (!err) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": mimeType,
        "Content-Length": contents.length,
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      });
      // res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      res.end(contents);
    } else {
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end();
    }
  });
}
```

Does anyone know how to put no cache in my code?

Comment: Use [`res.header()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set) (and/or [`res.setHeader()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)) before [`res.writeHead()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) if you want to mix them. `writeHead()` is final, so no additional headers can be added after it.

Comment: hi thanks.. I have tried to put res.header() before but I got error. On the other hand res.setHeader seems to work

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You've already written your headers.  I don't think you can add more after you've done that, so just put your headers in your first object.

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': mimeType,
  'Content-Length': contents.length,
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
});
```

Comment: If you use `res.set` you can set headers after *written your headers*, before `res.write` fires, may have changed since '13

Answer (score 150):

Make use of a middleware to add `no-cache` headers. Use this middleware where-ever you intend to turn caching off.

```
function nocache(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next();
}
```

Use the middleware in your routes definition:

```
app.get('/getfile', nocache, sendContent);

function sendContent(req, res) {
  var localPath = 'some-file';
  var mimeType = '';
  fs.readFile(localPath, 'utf8', function (err, contents) {
    if (!err && contents) {
      res.header('Content-Type', mimeType);
      res.header('Content-Length', contents.length);
      res.end(contents);
    } else {
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end();
    }
  });
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: He's not using Express.

Comment: Hi vmx... thanks but Brad is right I am not using Express and I think your answer is useful using only Express...

Comment: Ok, even if you aren't using express, what essentially needed is to set the nocache headers. I'm adding the headers in a reusable middleware, otherwise you can set those headers in any way that works.

Comment: I don't think using or not using express matters, here.

Answer (score 54):

Set these headers on your response:

```
'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
'Expires': '-1'
'Pragma': 'no-cache'
```

If you use express you can add this middleware to have no cache on all requests:

```
// var app = express()
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    next()
});
```

Comment: How is this different/an improvement over @vmx 's answer?

Answer (score 9):

You can use **nocache** Middleware to turn off caching.

```
npm install --save nocache
```

Apply the middleware to your app

```
const nocache = require('nocache');
...
app.use(nocache());
```

This disables browser caching.

Answer (score 2):

Pylinux's answer worked for me, but upon further inspection, I found the helmet module for express that handles some other security features for you.

http://webapplog.com/express-js-security-tips/

To use, install and require helmet in express.js, then call `app.use(helmet.noCache());`

Answer (score 0):

After spelunking through source code for the express and fresh modules, this works from the server side (before res.end is called):

```
req.headers['if-modified-since'] = undefined;
req.headers['if-none-match'] = undefined;
```

Nasty, but it works.