# Browser back button issue - (using sapui5, express and node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sapui5

I have an app using express and Node.js. In this app user login using credential and then generate JWT token to authenticate further HTTP request. I am trying to remove browser cache so when user log out there should be no browser cache web page when the user hit back/forward button. I did some research and tried some solutions but no success. One of them is -

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    next()
});
```

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429592/no-cache-in-a-nodejs-server/20429914#20429914 @OP: How are you implementing this? Did you double-check in the browser that the page loads with the stated headers?

Comment: @ChrisG - yes I see the stated header in the browser. I am using the same reference you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: This question is basically OT because we cannot replicate this. Can you put a [mcve] on github or the like?