# Why is the "last-modified" incorrect on Google Cloud Platform App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed my web on Google Cloud Platform App Engine several times. Using the setting as follows:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

Everything just worked fine when I tested it on the localhost.
But when I deployed it to Google Cloud Platform. The response header always is showing `last-modified: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:01 GMT`.
I have checked by `[my-web].df.r.appspot.com` to make sure that the problem is coming from Google Cloud Platform.

Does anyone have an idea?

**Updated 2020-10-07**
For anyone facing the same issue, please feel free to join the discussion [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168399701).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this is behaviour by design as all timestamps are made zero on deploy by app-engine. see: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168399701

I was sending the static files myself using express. So I solved it by not setting the etag and last-modified headers. For example:

```
app.use("/", express.static(root, { etag: false, lastModified: false }));
```

Or for individual files:

```
app.get("/*", async (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile("index.html", { root, lastModified: false, etag: false });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of old `index.html` being served. The problem was with the `etag` that was generated. Even though the files changed, the `etag` remained the same.

This caused the file to be served from browser's cache with status code 304. The culprit was my `app.yaml` file, which was

`runtime: nodejs10`

Changing it to below fixed the issue.

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs10
default_expiration: '14d'

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
    secure: always

  - url: .*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    expiration: '5s'
    secure: always
```

Comment: Is that runtime: nodejs10 is causing this issue?

Comment: it's unclear how exactly you fixed the excessive caching. your app.yaml contains `default_expiration: '14d'` which should cache files for 14d on the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a cache caused issue. To ensure that the new index.html is deployed, you would need to run “gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache”, additional fields may need to be added such as app.yaml as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/deploy). This would ensure that the new index.html associated with your version is pushed into the container.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. :(

Comment: Hi Benjamin, it seems like this issue is affecting more people, but when looking for a GCP issue tracker, no one has reported it yet. I would recommend that you open an issue tracker here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0 to report this directly to the GCP team.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue that previous version of index.html are getting picked up by clients after redeploying an appengine standard app. This problem seemed to start mid-August. We initially found that adding a line to the client HTML file like:  seemed to solve the problem. But this is no longer working.